# Additional s sound

Tags: pronunciation

> Was sind die Vorteile?

When I hear the German speaker speak this sentence, it sounds as if he is putting an *s* at the end of *sind*, as in

> Was sinds die Vorteile?

Am I hearing this correctly? If so, is there a rule that governs the addition of this *s* sound?

Comment: From which dialect region is the German speaker?

Comment: This isn't anything systematic. It is pronunciation mistake or speech defect of an individual.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Or the phonology of OP's native language is playing tricks upon him. I can see how hearing [sint] instead of [sind] could trick you into hearing [sinds].

Answer (score 5):

There is no *s*-sound after *sind* in Standard German. Depending on what your native language is, you might be confused by *Auslautverhärtung* ([final obstruent devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing)). The letter *d* is pronounced as *t* at the end of a syllable; and *t* can be more or less strongly [aspirated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant), yielding [zɪntʰ]. The aspiration is clearly audible in the following to examples:

- [Wiktionary's](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/De-sind.ogg) pronunciation of *sind* [zɪntʰ]
- *Geld regiert die Welt* [gɛltʰ ʁeˈgi:ɐ̯tʰ di: vɛltʰ] in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ0EnelPMVU)

Comment: But if that was the case, the example would in the same way have to write *Vortseile*. Also, aspiration of the allophone is much less likely if followed by another dental, because contraction might be preferable in that case (i.e. *wassin'die Vorteile*). Although, the aspiration might be especially notable if avoiding the contraction (e.g. theatrical actors speech might be transcribed with.*was sinthe die ...*, I guess). This careful pronunciation might be affected too, involuntary, if talking to a foreign speaker. In any case, it would be easier to ask the speaker?!

Answer (score 3):

This is not standard German. But in large parts of Bavaria to many verb this *s* is added when spoken. This applies mostly to the second person plural and questions:
"Geht*s* ihr heut noch in die Stadt?"
"Seid*s* ihr morgen dabei?"

Comment: Which is *absolutely not* happening in 3rd person, only in second.

Comment: In German as well as in English it's written Standard. It has nothing to do with Standarte ;) https://wortwuchs.net/standart-standard/

Comment: "This applies mostly to the second case plural and questions" - are you sure that isn't a subjective impression because that's a constellation that occurs very often in spoken language? Or, asked the other way round: Does "Die sans doch gestern gar net dabeigwesn!" sound unnatural?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper it must be without *s*: "De san doch...", but in 2pl "Ehs sads doch..."

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. The _s_ doesn't just appear in random places, it's precisely, not mostly, the second case plural where that happens. The _s_ the OP describes would not appear in any Bavarian dialect, since it is 3rd person.

Comment: Bavaria is huge. Exceptions might prove the rule. *hypercorrection* might happen, for example.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that might be true, as my point bases on observations. but as rexkognitas states, it still has to be 2nd person plural.

Comment: Seeing a bit of confusion here in the comments... I have some friends in Bavaria, and I observed this way of speaking when talking to them. Most of them come from around Regensburg, but this also is observable further south, towards Austria.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the speaker said *es* and then, after the pause, specified what is meant by *es*:

> Was sind's ... die Vorteile?

Answer (score 0):

At least in regions where Bavarian is spoken, this might be *s*' for *sie*. The standard version of the sentence would then be:

> Was sind sie, die Vorteile?

But that would require a very specific vernacular in between dialect and standard, since fully dialect wouldn't be "Was sinds" but "Wos sans".